# How to cheat *.so library into using missing @GLIBC_2.6 function?

Tags: shared-libraries, glibc, rhel

I need to run relatively new package on not-so-new RHEL 5.6.

I have 3rd party library (`lib3rdparty.so`) which is compiled against glibc 2.6 while RHEL 5.6 have only 2.5 installed. But in the library there is only a couple of references to `sched_getcpu@@GLIBC_2.6`. I've checked it like this

```
readelf -s lib3rdparty.so | egrep "@GLIBC_2.[6-9]"
```

to find references to something newer than `GLIBC_2.5` which is installed. The output is

```
0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND sched_getcpu@GLIBC_2.6 (62)
0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND sched_getcpu@@GLIBC_2.6
```

So, I have only one function from `GLIBC_2.6`. Now I want to make library think, that I have this function. For that purpose I forged small library (`libcheat.so`) like it mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660826/gcc-ld-create-a-new-libc-so-with-isoc99-sscanfglibc-2-7-symbol-from-glibc). Now I have `libcheat.so` file which, if run through `readelf`, will show this string:

```
10 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 sched_getcpu@@GLIBC_2.6
```

With this library I managed to succesfully build executable which is dynamically linked with `lib3rdparty.so`. Without this library I can't build anything, because `ld` can't find reference to `sched_getcpu`.

But the problem is with running this file: when I try to run it I have a following error:

```
 ./hello_world: version `GLIBC_2.6' not found (required by ./lib3rdparty.so)
```

So, I believe there is one last step to make it work, but I don't know what to do. I've tried to use `/etc/ld.conf.preload` and exporting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` so it would point to my library to load before others. But it won't run. Tried to run it through `strace` but have no meaningful output.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I believe I should mention "last step" which in my case included patching of binary 3rd party libraries.

1. Using `objdump` I found an address where `lib3rdparty.so` searches for `GLIBC_2.6`
2. Using `hexedit` I replaced this address with the one where `GLIBC_2.5` was exported (you should search for bytes in reversed order). Also I replaced symbol with 2.5.
3. Using `objdump` I've checked that all references now using `GLIBC_2.5`
4. I needed to rebuild `libcheat.so` as `sched_getcpu` now was referencing `GLIBC_2.5`, so I used `sched_getcpu@@GLIBC_2.5` as assembler inline

After that I put `libcheat.so` near `lib3rdparty.so`, set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `.` and my binary started to work. I'm not sure that this stuff will work totally correct, but if you stumbled into this kind of problem, this question and answer might be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the workaround you picked up is the best way to go. Why not supplying a newer glibc for the application? You can try to pass it over using the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable. For best binary compatibility, you can obtain a glibc binary from a newer distribution version, or rebuild a newer glibc version for RHEL 5.6.

Also, try to fiddle with the `LD_DEBUG` environment variable to see what the dynamic linker does.

Comment: I think that I use latest glibc for RHEL5, so newer ones only available for RHEL6. I've tried to find some info for upgrading glibc but nearly all of the advices are like "upgrade to newer RHEL". I'll try to pass newer version just for my application.

Comment: Tried to pass libc.so from Fedora 14. Ended with `ELF file OS ABI invalid`.

Comment: Best to use binaries from the distro on which lib3rdparty.so was originally built. If you can obtain a rootfs of it, or a VM image, you should be able to to build and test stuff on it.

Comment: I don't know where it was built as it is distributed as binaries. And also I need my program to work on my system with old glibc. This is the main problem. I have one system where compiled program works perfectly (Fedora) but this is of no help.