# undefined reference to __isoc99_sscanf

Tags: c++, c

I have a static C library `libex.a` that uses `sscanf`. Library was compiled using `-std=c99`

I want to use the library function in some C++ code that I am compiling using `-std=c++11`, but I get the following error:

```
lib/libex.a(srcfile.o): In function `my_function':
/srcpath/srcfile.c:215: undefined reference to `__isoc99_sscanf'
```

After poking around a bit, I have discovered that `sscanf` has issues with versions due to a backwards compatibility hack, hence the redirect to `__isoc99_sscanf`, so I suspect that is somehow the source of the problem. However, I checked my version of `glibc` and it looks recent enough that the solution suggested elsewhere (update your copy of `glibc` to at least 2.7) isn't helpful.

```
$ ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.19-0ubuntu6.6) 2.19
```

Any suggestions?

Of course, let me know if there's any additional information that would be relevant.

Thanks!

UPDATE: If I compile `libex.a` with `-D_GNU_SOURCE` the error message is changed to `undefined reference to sscanf`. Not sure if that will help figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: the C++ compiler 'mangles' function names.  The library, created in C, does not have mangled function names.  What header files are you including in your C++ source code?  Do those headers from the C language have the needed `extern "c" { ... wrappers?  so they can be used in C++?

Comment: Yes. All headers are wrapped with extern "C"

Comment: It'd help if you could make a minimal code example, and give the exact build commands for the library and  the c++ program

Comment: Good point. While trying to construct a minimal example, I was able to work out what was going on. (C++ code was linking to a nonstandard version of stdio.h that didn't support scanf). Thanks!

Comment: Also see question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3660826/39648

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else runs into this problem:

The Makefile for the C++ code disabled the standard libraries and start files using flags `-nostdlib -nodefaultlibs -nostartfiles`. It instead linked to the version of `stdio.h` included in the Intel SGX SDK for running inside enclaves. That version deprecates `sscanf`.